# How to identify android device uniquely as some way is depreciated recently

Tags: android, device, imei

How can I identify a device uniquely?

I have gone through some links and ans [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) but confused as most of the answer were written a long time ago and depreciated. what is the best way currently recommended by google?

Comment: Here is a thought : `Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) + Build.SERIAL;`

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would definitely go for the Device Id,Most safe and secure commonly used in today's Business Logics, U can retreive it by:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hardware is of device, it's always unique for every device.

How to retrieve device hardware id :

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

    Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```